# Python Import Class from different path

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, directory, path

File Directory

```
Folder1
    - FolderA
        -FolderAA
            -other.py
            -*.py
            -*.py
            -*.py
    - FolderB
        -myclass.py
```

Inside of myclass.py im trying to import a class and call a function inside of other.py.

This is a list of ways I have tried to import it.

```
import FolderA.FolderAA.other as myOther
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'FolderA'
```

```
import .FolderA.FolderAA.other as myOther
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it looks like everything is vaguely in the same place (not trying to import something from some arbitrary place on the filesystem) which makes everything much easier.

You have created some incomplete python packages. Good practice is to use lowercase names for packages, and snake case if it's more than one word.

The actual issue is that you need an `__init__.py` file in every directory. These files need no content, they only tell Python that the directories are packages.

```
folder_1/
  |_ __init__.py
  |_ folder_a/
     |_ __init__.py
     |_ folder_aa/
        |_ __init__.py
        |_ other.py
  |_ folder_by/
     |_ __init__.py
     |_ myclass.py
```

Then inside **myclass.py**

```py
from folder_1.folder_a.folder_aa import other
```

Comment: Could you provide what __init would look like if other.py has a single function called foo() Im lost at online examples

Comment: `__init__.py` is just an empty file. If other has `foo()`, you can use the line above in `myclass.py`, and then `other.foo()`.